# Гитхаб не работает

Tags: git, github, error404

Создаю репозиторий на гитхаб

[image: Создаю репозиторий на гитхаб]

И тут внезапно

[image: И тут внезапно]

У меня одного такое? Что делать, никто не знает? Неужели майкрософт убили гитхаб?(

Comment: Давно создали репозиторий? Еще не появился?

Comment: На фото показано.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что здесь не техподдержка GitHub.

Comment: @НикитаПавлов, фото на эти вопросы не отвечает: непонятно как давно вы сделала фото и появился ли уже репозиторий

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы со вчерашнего дня: https://status.github.com/messages

Но вообще это ресурс для ответов на вопросы про программирование и этот вопрос потеряет актуальность уже очень скоро. Рекомендую для таких целей использовать google

Comment: Не царское это дело лазить в гугле и что-то там искать и тратить время.... Хотя вы так чертовски правы :-)